# How to initialize multiple variable in single statement?

Tags: java, variables

I have below multiple variables.

```
JSONObject one = new JSONObject();
JSONObject two = new JSONObject();
JSONObject three = new JSONObject();
```

I tried below way

```
JSONObject one, two, three;
one = two = three = new JSONObject();
```

It is giving error when I am trying to write on those objects.

**[UPDATE]**

```
    JSONObject one = null, two = null , three = null ;
    one = two = three = new JSONObject();
    
    one.put("test", 1);
```

Comment: There is no way in Java

Comment: Really @NikolaiShevchenko. There is no way? I can't believe.

Comment: Perhaps you should say what error you are getting.

Comment: `JSONObject one = null, two = null , three = null ;` Note that the java compiler will initialize the variables to null. Explicitly initializing them to null actually adds more operations because you are initializing each variable twice. What is the motivation behind your question? Are you trying to save two lines of source code?

Answer (score 2):

According to your **[UPDATE]** section you can do like this:

```java
JSONObject one = null, two = null, three = null;
Stream.of(one, two, three).forEach(it -> it = new JSONObject());
```

But it's still not a single-statement initialization.

Comment: @Abra, no you are wrong. https://code.sololearn.com/cVRUy2BwauK8/#java

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to achieve. The code you posted yourself works.

```
one = two = three = new JSONObject();
```

However, you need to keep in mind that it creates only 1 object and assigns it to 3 different variable. If that object is mutable then you need to be careful. It is basicly equal to this:

```
JSONObject one = new JSONObject();
JSONObject two = one;
JSONObject three = two;
```

If you want to create 3 different objects and assign it to 3 different variable then it is not possible.